# Reading 2 Bytes from a .dat file

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a data file that stored like this :

6 byte (3*16-bits) header. 
- byte 0+1 (16-bits): x dimension 
- byte 2+3 (16-bits): y dimension 
- byte 4+5 (16-bits): z dimension
then: 3D volume data in x,y,z order. 16 bits (2 bytes) per voxel, only 12 bits of these 16 are used.

I want to load the data and store it in an array using C++

so how can I load 2 Bytes from a .data file the algorithm that I want to implement is

```
load(String filename)
{
 File fp = openfile(filename);
 Byte2 sizeX, sizeY, sizeZ;
 sizeX = readfile(sizeof(Byte2),fp);
 sizeY = readfile(sizeof(Byte2),fp);
 sizeZ = readfile(sizeof(Byte2),fp);
 UnsignedShort data[sizeX*sizeY*sizeZ];
 for(Integer z=0; z < sizeZ; z++) {
    for(Integer y=0; y < sizeY; y++) {
       for(Integer x=0; x < sizeX; x++) {
        data[x+y*sizeX+z*sizeX*sizeY] = readfile(sizeof(Byte2),fp);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: OK since no one answer yet
can anyone at least tell me how can I use BinaryReader in C++ ?
if there is a tutorial or example I'll be thankful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using an `ifstream` object to read the data file. When you open a file in C++, you can mention that you want to [read the data in binary](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ifstream/open/) instead of text. There is no direct equivalent of Java's `BinaryReader` in C++.

More details on `ifstream` can be found in this [C++ reference page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ifstream/).